# Error with AR camera, freezes until crash

Tags: android, augmented-reality

im developing a simple Ar camera using the lirbray `"com.gorisse.thomas.sceneform:sceneform:1.21.0"`, the app seems to work fine until it freezes for seconds then returns normal and freezes again until it crashes. Im currently using a Realme gt master edition to try my project, ive been trying to use it in other phones but it ocurs the same error.

The error trace:

```
W/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): cancelRequest:518: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1204)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:99)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1322)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:580)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:791)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:279)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: cancelRequest:518: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38) (code 10)
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2455)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2408)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2350)
        at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUser.java:749)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:97)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1322) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:580) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:791) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:279) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
W/CameraDevice(0): Device disconnected.
E/StartedCameraController(0): Device closing due to unexpected device event: DeviceErrorEvent(errorType=ERROR_CAMERA_DISCONNECTED)
```

My build gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.porfavor"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //the library im using
    implementation "com.gorisse.thomas.sceneform:sceneform:1.21.0"
}
```

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        FragmentOnAttachListener,
        BaseArFragment.OnTapArPlaneListener,
        BaseArFragment.OnSessionConfigurationListener,
        ArFragment.OnViewCreatedListener  {

    private ArFragment arFragment;
    private Renderable model;
    private ViewRenderable viewRenderable;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().addFragmentOnAttachListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            if (Sceneform.isSupported(this)) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.arFragment, ArFragment.class, null)
                        .commit();
            }
        }

        loadModels();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment.getId() == R.id.arFragment) {
            arFragment = (ArFragment) fragment;
            arFragment.setOnSessionConfigurationListener(this);
            arFragment.setOnViewCreatedListener(this);
            arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(this);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionConfiguration(Session session, Config config) {
        if (session.isDepthModeSupported(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC)) {
            config.setDepthMode(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(ArSceneView arSceneView) {
        arFragment.setOnViewCreatedListener(null);

        // Fine adjust the maximum frame rate
        arSceneView.setFrameRateFactor(SceneView.FrameRate.HALF);
    }


    public void loadModels() {
        WeakReference<MainActivity> weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(this);
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, R.raw.tigre)
                .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
                .setAsyncLoadEnabled(true)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(model -> {
                    MainActivity activity = weakActivity.get();
                    if (activity != null) {
                        activity.model = model;
                    }
                })
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            this, "Unable to load model", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return null;
                });
        ViewRenderable.builder()
                .setView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(viewRenderable -> {
                    MainActivity activity = weakActivity.get();
                    if (activity != null) {
                        activity.viewRenderable = viewRenderable;
                    }
                })
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load model", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return null;
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTapPlane(HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (model == null || viewRenderable == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Create the Anchor.
        Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

        // Create the transformable model and add it to the anchor.
        TransformableNode model = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        model.setParent(anchorNode);
        model.setRenderable(this.model)
                .animate(true).start();
        model.select();

        Node titleNode = new Node();
        titleNode.setParent(model);
        titleNode.setEnabled(false);
        titleNode.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        titleNode.setRenderable(viewRenderable);
        titleNode.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Porfavor">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />

</application>
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android/issues/328 and https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android/issues/383

Answer (score 0):

Your

`ViewRenderable.builder().setView(this, R.layout.activity_main).build()`
is wrong.

You should create a new view_model_title layout and paste this textView

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dp"
android:text="YourApp"
android:textAlignment="center" />
```

then put it in the place of activity_main.
Of course use the activity_main layout as your ContentView layout.